# Python: Display Shape from Tetris Game

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code that will display a shape from tetris on a board. I keep getting this error and don't know how to fix it:

> TypeError: unbound method can_move() must be called with O_shape instance as first argument (got Board instance instead)

Here is my code:

```
class Board():

    def __init__(self, win, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        # create a canvas to draw the tetris shapes on
        self.canvas = CanvasFrame(win, self.width * Block.BLOCK_SIZE + Block.OUTLINE_WIDTH,
                                        self.height * Block.BLOCK_SIZE + Block.OUTLINE_WIDTH)
        self.canvas.setBackground('light gray')

        # create an empty dictionary
        # currently we have no shapes on the board
        self.grid = {}

    def draw_shape(self, shape):
        ''' Parameters: shape - type: Shape
            Return value: type: bool

            draws the shape on the board if there is space for it
            and returns True, otherwise it returns False
        '''
        if shape.can_move(self, 0, 0):
            shape.draw(self.canvas)
            return True
        return False

class Tetris():

    SHAPES = [I_shape, J_shape, L_shape, O_shape, S_shape, T_shape, Z_shape]
    DIRECTION = {'Left':(-1, 0), 'Right':(1, 0), 'Down':(0, 1)}
    BOARD_WIDTH = 10
    BOARD_HEIGHT = 20

    def __init__(self, win):
        self.board = Board(win, self.BOARD_WIDTH, self.BOARD_HEIGHT)
        self.win = win
        self.delay = 1000 #ms

        # sets up the keyboard events
        # when a key is called the method key_pressed will be called
        self.win.bind_all('<Key>', self.key_pressed)

        # set the current shape to a random new shape
        self.current_shape = self.create_new_shape()

        # Draw the current_shape oan the board 
        self.board.draw_shape(self.current_shape)


    def create_new_shape(self):
        ''' Return value: type: Shape

            Create a random new shape that is centered
             at y = 0 and x = int(self.BOARD_WIDTH/2)
            return the shape
        '''

        # YOUR CODE HERE
        y = 0
        x = int(self.BOARD_WIDTH/2)
        the_shape = random.choice(self.SHAPES)
        return the_shape
```

Comment: I believe my problem lies somewhere in the self.board.draw_shape(self.current_shape) line. I went over this with a friend who hinted that I look there or in the create_new_shape function for my problem but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

you didn't post the code for the relevant method (`can_move()`).
besides, the error message is self explanatory, it expects a parameter of type `O_shape` but you're calling the method and passing it a `Board` instead.

```
def draw_shape(self, shape):
''' Parameters: shape - type: Shape
    Return value: type: bool

    draws the shape on the board if there is space for it
    and returns True, otherwise it returns False
'''
  if shape.can_move(self, 0, 0): # <-- you probably meant to call shape.can_move(0,0)
    shape.draw(self.canvas)
    return True
  return False
```

methods that are bound to a class have the instance passed as the first parameter implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to instantiate your shape classes.

```
SHAPES = [I_shape(), J_shape(), L_shape(), O_shape(), S_shape(), T_shape(), Z_shape()]
```

But you should only have a single `Shape` class that takes arguments to turn them into the various shapes.

Comment: He could have a class for each shape (the "draw" method might be hardcoded for each one).  But then, the class should be instantiated in the `the_shape = random.choice(self.SHAPES)` line.

Comment: This is incorrect, the SHAPES list provides a handy list of references to the different shape classes (one per tetromino).  You then instantiate the shape classes via SHAPES[<random number>](<args>).